# What does QueryClientCertificate in LDAPConnector class does?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

I am writing a tool to make an LDAPS connection on port 636 to different Directory Services. Using LDAPConnection of c# class I am able to successfully connect to the AD Server on both  Port 389 and 636 now.

But, what i don't understand is, previously as I read somewhere, had added the below code to disable client certificate verification:

```
public X509Certificate ClientCertFinder(LdapConnection connection,byte[][] trustedCAs) {
        return null;
    }

if (sslEnabled){
        ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = sslEnabled;
        SessionOptions.QueryClientCertificate = new QueryClientCertificateCallback(ClientCertFinder);
    }
```

With the above code, i was not able to connect to Active Directory on port 636 (Search operation throws `An Operation Error Occurred`), but i was able to connect to other Directory Services on port 636. Just by chance i removed

```
SessionOptions.QueryClientCertificate = new QueryClientCertificateCallback(ClientCertFinder);
```

And now the program is connecting to all the Directory Services, including AD on Port 636.

This clearly show i don't understand the use of QueryClientCertificate. Can some please explain, why this is used?

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to an LDAP server using a secure a LDAP connection (LDAPS), you'll typically use these two methods in tandem :

1. `QueryClientCertificate` - Retrieve the certificate from a byte array of root certificate authorities
2. `VerifyServerCertificate` - Verify certificate was issued to the third party you're connecting to

By removing that line of code, all you're doing is bypassing the retrieval of the client's certificate, which also means you're bypassing validating it against a root CA. However, as you've likely realized, in order for the connection to still be properly established, you need to perform an SSL handshake, and also set the `SecureSocketLayer` flag to `true`. The actual verification can be forced using a delegate that just returns true :

```
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = SSL;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += delegate { return true; };
```

Keep in mind, though, this isn't something you'll always want to do, especially if security becomes a concern. There can be incredibly sensitive user information stored in a directory server, so it's easy to understand why these exist. However, if the server you're connecting to is issuing a self-signed certificate (because who wants to pay for a real one?), then this procedure is a must, since a self-signed certificate will not be valid with a root CA.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As you said i realized the use of the property "VerifyServerCertificate". But i still don't understand, why would removing an assignment of delegation to "QueryClientCertificate" would make the connection go through.

Answer (score 0):

The QueryClientCertificate callback is used if you want to use client certs (e.g. on a smartcard) to authenticate to the LDAP server. If you simply want to use credentials (e.g. a username and password), this isn't necessary.

Comment: Hey Thanks. This is what i thought was the use and so i returned null from delegate function. But when i returned null, i was not able to connect to AD over LDAPS and threw the exception "An Operation Error occurred". When i removed the assignment of delegation, the connection went through. Now i wonder, what happens in this call back  when i don't delegate.

Comment: I would venture to guess it's simply not attempting client cert AuthN at all